# Ion-nav-bar : Need help working with scopes and emit in Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

So, I'm using the sidenav and I'm having trouble making my navbar dynamic.

**It used to work with this:**

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-class="$root.color"></ion-nav-bar>

controller('childStateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$root.color = 'state-color';
}
```

**That method stopped working though.**

**This is the basic idea of what I've got going on now:**

```
controller('SidenavCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.color = '';
    $scope.$on('stateColor', function(event,data) {
        vm.color = data;
        return vm.color;
}   }

<ion-nav-bar ng-class="{{vm.color}}"></ion-nav-bar>
```

**I tried emit in other controllers but right now I have it in the config like this:**

```
$stateProvider.state('sidenav.childState', {
    views: {
        'sidenav-view': {
            onEnter: function($scope) {
                $scope.$emit('colorChange', 'new-color');
}   }   }   }
```

Comment: have you tried $rootScope.$broadcast()? instead of emit

Comment: I thought emit sent changes up the hierarchy and broadcast sent them down. Either way, I just tried it with broadcast and rootScope but it didn't work.

Comment: what you say is correct but you are emitting from stateProvider resolve which actually is executed right before the controller afaik :)

Comment: Isn't onEnter an event callback though? I'm still trying to get a handle on watchers. The way I'm seeing it is: $on has a function that is called for a specified event. When states change, onEnter triggers $emit with that event and some data. The data is then sent up the scope for that function to use. Is that logic sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still appreciate any input on how $on/$emit/$broadcast could have worked for this, but I got my dynamic nav-bar with a simpler method that doesn't create any unnecessary scopes.

For anybody else trying to make a nav-bar with dynamic colors:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 
             ng-class:{'bar-positive': $state.includes('*.state1.**'),
                       'bar-assertive': $state.includes('*.state2.**')};">
</ion-nav-bar>
```

I globbed my states there so that their children can also return true.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure it will not work cause you are emitting/broadcasting before the controller gets executed, anyway you can try:

```
$stateProvider.state('sidenav.childState', {
    views: {
        'sidenav-view': {
            onEnter: function($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('colorChange', 'new-color');
}   }   }   }

controller('SidenavCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.color = '';
    $scope.$on('colorChange', function(event, data) {

       console.log('New color is ' + data);
}   }
```

I think the proper way is to use a directive for your element it could ba a css class/ data attribute or element it self, as you wish.

Comment: How would you suggest I do it? I prefer not using loads of scopes. I tried with a provider service but that failed as well.

Comment: @RyanUsumi i would do a directive and observe the attr-color="" for example, but depends why you need it on stateProvider resolve ?